# Load image from binary base64

Tags: android, android-volley, universal-image-loader

EDIT: This is a bug in Android version <4.3 Kitkat. It relates to the libjpeg library in Android, which can't handle JPEGs with missing EOF/EOI bits, or apparently with metadata/EXIF data that it doesn't like.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9064

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have an issue when loading an image in my app.

My endpoint sends `JSON` which contains a `BASE64` encoded image. Depending on the REST call, these images can be `PNG` or `JPG`. Some of the `JPG` files suffer from an issue where they are missing an `EOF` bit at the end. The `PNG` files work, and some `JPG` files work, but unfortunately a lot of these `JPG` files with the issue are present in the Oracle DB (stored as `BLOB`). I don't have control of the DB.

I have been looking through Google bugs here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9064
and here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57502

The issue is also seen where the encoding is `CYMK` using a custom ICC profile.

Decoding the image the standard way returns `false`:

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base64ImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
```

According to the bug reports above, the built in JPG parser in Android is to blame.

I'm trying to figure out a workaround for my device, which is stuck on `4.2.2`. I have no other option on this OS version.

I thought it might be a good idea to try and use an image loader library like `Universal Image Loader`, but it requires I either have the image stored locally, or stored on a URL. As I get the data in `BASE64` from the REST server, I can't use this. An option is to support `decodeByteArray` in a custom class that extends `BaseImageDecoder`, as stated by the dev at the bottom here: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/209

Here's where I get stuck. I already have a custom image decoder to try handle the issue of the missing `EOF` marker in the JPG file, but I don't know how to edit it to add support for `decodeByteArray`.

Here is my `CustomImageDecoder`:

```
public class CustomImageDecoder extends BaseImageDecoder {

    public CustomImageDecoder(boolean loggingEnabled) {
        super(loggingEnabled);
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream getImageStream(ImageDecodingInfo decodingInfo) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = decodingInfo.getDownloader()
                .getStream(decodingInfo.getImageUri(), decodingInfo.getExtraForDownloader());
        return stream == null ? null : new JpegClosedInputStream(stream);
    }

    private class JpegClosedInputStream extends InputStream {

        private static final int JPEG_EOI_1 = 0xFF;
        private static final int JPEG_EOI_2 = 0xD9;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private int bytesPastEnd;

        private JpegClosedInputStream(final InputStream iInputStream) {
            inputStream = iInputStream;
            bytesPastEnd = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            int buffer = inputStream.read();
            if (buffer == -1) {
                if (bytesPastEnd > 0) {
                    buffer = JPEG_EOI_2;
                } else {
                    ++bytesPastEnd;
                    buffer = JPEG_EOI_1;
                }
            }

            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, using the above custom class, I am trying to load my byte array like this:

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(formattedB64String, Base64.NO_WRAP);
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
String imageId = "stream://" + is.hashCode();
...
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.displayImage(imageId, userImage, options);
```

and I get this error:
`ImageLoader: Image can't be decoded [stream://1097215584_656x383]`

Universal Image loader does not allow the `stream://` schema, so I created a custom `BaseImageDownloader` class that allows it:

```
public class StreamImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {

    private static final String SCHEME_STREAM = "stream";
    private static final String STREAM_URI_PREFIX = SCHEME_STREAM + "://";

    public StreamImageDownloader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
        if (imageUri.startsWith(STREAM_URI_PREFIX)) {
            return (InputStream) extra;
        } else {
            return super.getStreamFromOtherSource(imageUri, extra);
        }
    }
}
```

So if anyone can help me create a better `CustomImageDecoder` that handles  a `BASE64` encoded string, or a `byte[]` containing an image so I can use `decodeByteArray`, I would be grateful!

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of hard work to achieve low performance. Base64 encode adds 33% extra weight to the data and takes up processor at both ends. And clearly you are having trouble coding it too. Why not simply put the image url in your json?

Comment: I would put the image url in the JSON, but the image is stored as a `BLOB` in the database. I should have mentioned that in my initial question.

Comment: Also, even if I linked directly to the file, Android still wouldn't display it, because it has problems displaying that type of JPEG. I did download the file, and while it would show in the layout preview in Android Studio, once I ran it on a device or emulator, the image would be blank. Really, I need to just get the `BASE64` string into any usable object, which I can then manipulate. But as it stands, Android simply won't let me do anything with the `BASE64` string!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off:
The issue here is actually a bug in Android <4.3 where Android can't display images that either aren't closed properly (missing end bytes) or contain certain metadata that, for some reason, it doesn't like. I'm not sure what metadata this is, however. My issue was with JPEGs not being terminated properly.

The bug is fixed in Android 4.3 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`UnversalImageLoader` uses the following schemes to decode the files

```
"h t t p ://site.com/image.png" // from Web
"file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png" // from SD card
"file:///mnt/sdcard/video.mp4" // from SD card (video thumbnail)
"content://media/external/images/media/13" // from content provider
"content://media/external/video/media/13" // from content provider (video thumbnail)
"assets://image.png" // from assets
"drawable://" + R.drawable.img // from drawables (non-9patch images)
```

your scheme is `stream://`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, yes that is correct. I apologise though, I left out one piece of information in my initial question. I extended `BaseImageDownloader` to allow the `stream://` scheme. I will edit it now.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. I meant it was correct that my scheme was `stream://`. However, I said I have extended `BaseImageDownloader` to accept the `stream://` schema. I then edited my question to include this code. I have yet to find a solution to this problem.